# Фигура внутри буквы css

Tags: html, css, web-fonts

Здраствуйте, хочу спросить, как мне сделать внутри буквы О такой овал. Через position я могу сделать, но я хочу, чтобы логотип мог изменяться по размерам, и ничего не съезжало. Заранее спасибо)

[image: font]

Comment: Шрифт любой или определенный?

Comment: Любой, мне просто принцип понять

Comment: это не то чтобы вот так просто, можно или символ в шрифт добавить или изменить, или же все нарисовать в svg

Comment: Если это логотип, то слой сводится в единый и сохраняется в формате png\jpg\svg и масштабируется нормально все вместе. Если же раздельно и без абсолютов, то узнать что за шрифт, скорее-всего определенный шрифт с такой буквой О

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать специальные(unicode) символы, символ ◉ в виде escape последовательности в html можно добавить так:

```
&#9673;
```

или просто скопировать

```css
.logo {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='logo'>LE◉ IMAGES</div>
```

Так же можно создать свой / подключить готовый  [иконочный шрифт](https://fontawesome.com/)